# ShareKit Localization

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sharekit

I am currently using ShareKit 2.0 for twitter and FB intergration. The problem I'm having is I need to add a language which is not supported by ShareKit. ShareKit uses a seperate .bundle with lproj for each langauge . Please give me directions to add my own lproj to the sharekit ?

Or Basically how to add a lproj file to a .bundle file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your lproj file to `ShareKit/ShareKit.bundle`. For example:

```
cp -r en.lproj ShareKit/ShareKit.bundle/
```